# Node: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Im trying to create a simple CRUD app in node js and i get **Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]** on the `router.get("/:id", userController.getUser);` line

Routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const userController= require('../controllers/userController.js')

const router = express.Router()

/* READ */
router.get("/:id", userController.getUser);

module.exports = router
```

Controller.js

```
const getUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
}

const Function..

const AnotherFunction..


module.exports = {
   getUser,
   Function,
  AnotherFunction,
}
```

console.log(userController.getUser.toString()) prints:

```
async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Just above the `router.get` try to log `console.log(userController.getUser.toString())`. This will help debug

Comment: userController.getUser returns undefined. Check controllers.js properly exports.

Comment: @RahulPurohit Its correct. It Prints out my getUser function

Comment: @Chryzz Interesting! Did you try writing full function instead of arrow?

Comment: Also please share the log here want to see

Comment: @RahulPurohit Updated the code. And yes i get the same error with full function instead of arrow:(

Comment: If this is a toy project can you share the github link or share a codesandbox so we can take a proper view

Comment: @RahulPurohit Thank you for your time. https://github.com/name-in-use/MERN-Website/tree/master/server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have correct access rights to push into your repo so explaining the issue here.

In your `auth.js` you have exported `verifyToken` function as default export.

`module.exports = verifyToken`.

But ***you are destructuring*** when importing in `postsController.js`

`const {verifyToken} = require ('../middleware/auth.js')`

Importing like this will get the correct function =>

`const verifyToken = require("../middleware/auth.js");`

Change your postsController file as below. It should work.

```
const express = require("express");
const verifyToken = require("../middleware/auth.js");
module.exports = verifyToken;
```